# Preferences vs singleton class to store data centrally in android

Tags: android

Should I use a singleton class or preferences to store the data that is shared in the program. For example, say the user can enable or disable location tracking. The state of tracking has to be stored and shared with the SERVICE that handles the location changes. In such case, should I use a singleton class or preferences to persist the choice for a background SERVICE ? Please also relevant supporting points to your choice.

Comment: I would use singletons for a data structure that is needed throughout and preferences for preferences/settings etc. I don't think everyone likes the singleton route but that's the way I was taught.

Comment: You have to use SharedPreferences to store any settings (like your location tracking) that need to persist through application closes/restarts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of SharedPreference is exactly store preference settings and status values.
Singleton restricts the instantiation of a class to one object, that is a different matter.

If you want to avoid the lost of data when the application is closed, if you don't use Preferences you have to create manually a method to store and load your data on a file, so SharedPreference is the best choice, if you want to share an object only **during the program execution** you can use singleton to restrict its instantiation, however if the value to store is a String or a primitive using Preference also in this case has no side effects but is a bit *dirty* programming choice.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton - Saves Data in variables and get deleted when Application is Destroyed.
Shared Prefs - Save Data outside of your Application so u can later use even application is destoryed.

Answer (score -1):

`SharedPreferences`, `Service`, and Singletons are substantially different. None of them can be used INSTEAD of the other one. If at ANY situation you though you can use one instead of the other, you can be sure you did not understand their application very well.

As one example difference, SharePrefs are saved in the disc so they are persistent, while Singletons are not.